# SQL query to find rows with the same value in multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to find rows in my table that have duplicate values accross columns *in a the same row*

Example:

```
id   column_1    column_2    column_3
1    123            44           100
2    555            555          555
3    101            396          100
4    99             99           99
5    123            44           100
```

I need a query that returns rows 2 & 4. So far, I have only found questions with similar titles that refer to finding rows that have the same values in multiple columns that would for example return 1 & 5. That's **not** what I am looking for :)

Comment: `where col1=col2 and col2=col3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE column_1 = column_2 AND column_2 = column_3
```

Answer (score 1):

*Substraction* may be used for three columns :

```
select *
  from mytable
 where ( column_1 - column_2  =  column_3 - column_2 )
   and column_1 = column_2
order by 1;
```

or *least* and *greatest* functions may be used together :

```
select *
  from mytable    
 where greatest(column_1,column_2,column_3) = least(column_1,column_2,column_3)
order by 1;
```

[*SQL Fiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/029f6/6)

Comment: `least` and `greatest` are not aggregate functions. No need for `group by` in your 2nd query, it's a simple `WHERE greatest(column_1,column_2,column_3) = least(column_1,column_2,column_3)`

Comment: @dnoeth exactly, danke schön.